# golang download file and follow redirects

Tags: go

i want to download file from redirect url, and return filename in variable filename, my actual code is :

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io"
)

func downloadFile(filepath string, url string) (err error) {

  // Create the file
  out, err := os.Create(filepath)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }
  defer out.Close()

  // Get the data
  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  // Writer the body to file
  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}

func main() {

  var filename string = "urls.txt"
  var url1 string = "http://94.177.247.162:5000/random"

  downloadFile(filename, url1)

}
```

how i can change my code to return real name of file downloaded in variable filename.

example output :

```
urlix.txt
```

Comment: How is the filename provided to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirects should be followed by default. You can get the final url visited to aquire the download using

`finalURL := resp.Request.URL.String()`

The last part of the url is your filename on the remote so something like this should work

`parts := strings.Split(finalURL, "/")
filename := parts[len(parts)-1]`

Comment: how i can update in my situation ? because need create the file first to do request

Comment: In your example I cant see any reason why you couldn't move file creation down below the request, if you need the filename you can return from the download function. If you really need to get it up front I think http.Head() will work - not 100% sure if this follows redirects without testing though, you may need to explicitly tell it to do so